# Parsing with regular expression: Copy link from one html tag to other html tag

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

**I need to copy the link from canonical html tag to the other tags below**

`<link rel="canonical" href="https://website.com/en/camera.html" />`

and

```
<div class="somers"><a href="https://website/fffffon.html" class="flags bg" hreflang="bg" title="bk"></a>
<a href="https://website.com/test-lofet.html" class="flags sk" hreflang="sk" title="sk"></a>
<a href="https://website.com/america.html" class="flags uk" hreflang="uk" title="uk"></a>
```

**The output should be**

```
<div class="somers"><a href="https://website.com/en/camera.html" class="flags bg" hreflang="bg" title="bk"></a>
<a href="https://website.com/en/camera.html" class="flags sk" hreflang="sk" title="sk"></a>
<a href="https://website.com/en/camera.html" class="flags uk" hreflang="uk" title="uk"></a>
```

My solution replace only the first line...

**Search:** `(?s)<link rel="canonical" href="(.*?)"\h/>.*?<a href="\K.*?(?="\hclass="flags)`

**Replace by:** `\1`

Comment: This can't be done in a single step with Notepad++. You have to run the modification as many times as needed to change all the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works with PowerShell, that will replace all lines with the canonical link tag:

```
$sourcedir = "C:\Folder1\"
$resultsdir = "C:\Folder1\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcedir -Filter *.html | ForEach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw
    $replaceValue = (Select-String -InputObject $content -Pattern '(?<=<link rel="canonical" href=").+(?=" />)').Matches.Value
    $content = $content -replace '(?<=<a href=").+(?=</a>)',$replaceValue
    Set-Content -Path $resultsdir\$($_.name) $content
}
```